# Then prove: $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ if $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

If $\vec{v} \in V$ such that $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$, $\forall \vec{u} \in V$.

Then prove: $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$

I tired to solve by assuming that they are $\langle u,v\rangle \neq 0$ $\rightarrow$ $u,v$ are not orthogonal, and if they are not orthogonal then $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ can only be true if and only if $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$.

Is this correct? Or is there any other alternative way?

Comment: Since $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$ is true for all $u$, what about $\langle v, v\rangle$?

Comment: @Arthur $<v,v> = ll v ll$ ??

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, by defintion, if and only if $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$. So the way you've described doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @aavatar It seems you may not be aware that given some inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, we can define a norm by $||v|| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$. From this it follows that $\langle v,v \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow ||v|| = 0 \Rightarrow v = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way:  pick $u = v$: then

$\Vert v \Vert^2 = \langle v, v \rangle = 0,  \tag{1}$

which implies

$\Vert v \Vert = 0, \tag{2}$

i.e.

$v = 0. \tag{3}$

***QED!***

***Note Added Thursday 16 April 2015 3:23 PM PST:***  The usual definition of an inner product on a vector space $V$ specifies that $\langle v, v \rangle \ge 0$, $\forall v \in V$ with $\langle v, v \rangle = 0$ iff $v = 0$.  This allows the definition of $\Vert v \Vert = \langle v, v \rangle^{1/2}$ to proceed, with the consequence that $\Vert v \Vert = 0$ precisely when $v = 0$. These notions are reasonably widely known, and assumed so here.  See  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Just a quick question, why did we choose u = v?

Comment: Basically because it works.  $u = v \in V$ is avaiable to us and fits nicely with the definition of $\Vert v \Vert$ , my eq. (1).  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

$$
u = v\in V \Rightarrow 0 = u \cdot v = v\cdot v = \lVert v \rVert^2 \Rightarrow \lVert v \rVert = 0 \Rightarrow v = 0
$$

1. property of task
2. definition scalar product $a \cdot b = \lVert a \rVert \, \lVert b \rVert \cos \angle(a,b)$
3. property of squares
4. property of vector norm

Answer (score 3):

If  v is a fixed vector and $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for all u $\in V$, then in particular for $u=e_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

We know also that $v=a_1e_1+\ldots+a_ne_n$
 Then $\langle e_1,v\rangle=0=a_1\langle e_1,e_1\rangle+\ldots+a_n\langle e_1,e_n\rangle=a1\langle e_1,e_1\rangle$

but $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle \neq 0$ so $a_1=0$.

Make an analogous process with all $e_i$ and you will find that $v=0$.